# ML - invalid instruction operands on sar,shl (?)

Tags: assembly, masm

Getting "error A2070: invalid instruction operands" on the following instructions in assembly code (generated from CL)

```
mov edx, DWORD PTR ?_Var2@@3JA      
shl edx, 1326   ;this line gets the error

mov ecx, DWORD PTR ?_Var3@@3JA
shl ecx, 1514   ;this line gets the error

mov ecx, DWORD PTR __Var4$74314[ebp]
sar ecx, 3811   ;this line gets the error
```

It is not happening here:

```
; Line 698
movsx   edx, BYTE PTR ?_Var5@@3PAHA+4
movsx   ecx, BYTE PTR ?_Var6@@3PADA+1
sar edx, cl
```

Maybe something to do with the fact that shl,sar is being used with constants rather than registers?
Confused :(

Comment: It might be because your immediate values are too high for shifting (normally the immediate value is between `1 <= count <= 31`)

Comment: You're correct - thank you sir

Comment: For shift instructions, the immediate value is a signed 8 bit value, but only the bottom 5 bits are used. Microsoft assembler will allow something like shl edx,32 which will be a nop. shl edx,255 or shl edx,-1 or shl edx,31 would do the same thing. The error here is caused by a value too big for an immediate signed 8 bit value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `edx` and other registers are size 32 bits, shifting them by more than 32 bits is not meaningful. That's why the assembler  issues an error.

Comment: An "immediate" shift value is encoded into the instruction. It can't hold the value you required.